# Print raw "^" char with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write "^^" when hitting the key "^" twice.

I had this:

```
:*:^::{^}{^}
```

which worked well.
But I had to reinstall my system in order to install Win10 fall creator update and I may have updated autohotkey (according to the date of the latest release 11st Feb 2018).

but now, this hotkey replacement line is doing this:

```
^^^
```

that is ^^ and if I press space, it adds ^

What has changed? Is there an autohotkey option that I missed?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

found a solution at last:

```
:*b0:^::{^}
```